# What does the Amazon ELB automatic health check do and what does it expect?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

Here is the thing:

1. We've implemented a C++ RESTful API Server, with built-in HTTP parser and no standard HTTP server like apache or anything of the kind
2. It has been in use for several months in Amazon structure, using both plain and SSL communications, and no problems have been identified, related to Amazon infra-structure
3. We are deploying our first backend using Amazon ELB
4. Amazon ELB has a customizable health check system but also as an automatic one, as stated [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/ts-elb-healthcheck.html)
5. We've found no documentation of what data is sent by the health check system
6. The backend simple hangs on the socket read instruction and, eventually, the connection is closed

I'm not looking for a solution for the problem since the backend is not based on a standard web server, just if someone knows what kind of message is being sent by the ELB health check system, since we've found no documentation about this, anywhere.

Help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> Amazon ELB has a customizable health check system but also as an
>   automatic one, as stated [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/ts-elb-healthcheck.html)

With *customizable* you are presumably referring to the health check configurable via the AWS Management Console (see [Configure Health Check Settings](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/configure-healthcheck.html)) or via the API (see [ConfigureHealthCheck](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/APIReference/API_ConfigureHealthCheck.html)).

The requirements to pass health checks configured this way are outlined in field *Target* of the [HealthCheck](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/APIReference/API_HealthCheck.html) data type documentation:

> Specifies the instance being checked. The protocol is either TCP,
>   HTTP, HTTPS, or SSL. The range of valid ports is one (1) through
>   65535.
>
> **Note**
>
> - TCP is the default, specified as a TCP: port pair, for example
>     "TCP:5000". In this case a healthcheck simply attempts to open a TCP
>     connection to the instance on the specified port. **Failure to connect
>     within the configured timeout is considered unhealthy.**
> - SSL is also specified as SSL: port pair, for example, SSL:5000.
> - **For HTTP or HTTPS protocol, the situation is different.** You have to
>     include a ping path in the string. HTTP is specified as a
>     HTTP:port;/;PathToPing; grouping, for example
>     "HTTP:80/weather/us/wa/seattle". In this case, a HTTP GET request is
>     issued to the instance on the given port and path. **Any answer other
>     than "200 OK" within the timeout period is considered unhealthy.**
> - The total length of the HTTP ping target needs to be 1024 16-bit
>     Unicode characters or less.
>
> *[emphasis mine]*

With *automatic* you are presumably referring to the health check described in paragraph *Cause* within [Why is the health check URL different from the URL displayed in API and Console?](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/ts-elb-healthcheck.html#ts-elb-healthcheck-different-url):

> **In addition to the health check you configure for your load balancer,
>   a second health check is performed** by the service to protect against
>   potential side-effects caused by instances being terminated without
>   being deregistered. To perform this check, the load balancer opens a
>   TCP connection on the same port that the health check is configured to
>   use, and then closes the connection after the health check is
>   completed. *[emphasis mine]*

The paragraph *Solution* clarifies the payload being zero here, i.e. it is similar to the non HTTP/HTTPS method described for the configurable health check above:

> This extra health check does not affect the performance of your
>   application because it is not sending any data to your back-end
>   instances. You cannot disable or turn off this health check.

### Summary / Solution

Assuming your *RESTful API Server, with built-in HTTP parser* is supposed to serve HTTP only indeed, you will need to handle two health checks:

1. The first one you configured yourself *as a HTTP:port;/;PathToPing* - you'll receive a `HTTP GET` request and must answer with `200 OK` within the specified timeout period to be considered healthy.
2. The second one configured automatically by the service - it will open a TCP connection on the HTTP port configured above, won't send any data, and then closes the connection after the health check is completed.

In conclusion it seems that your server might be behaving perfectly fine already and you are just irritated by the 2nd health check's behavior - does ELB actually consider your server to be unhealthy?

Comment: Does anyone know how to configure nginx to not log these events? Logging 10,000+ of these events a day does indeed "affect the performance of your application"

Comment: Don't know if this was possible before but you can now edit the Health Check, simplest thing in my case was to switch the protocol from `HTTP` to `TCP` albeit still over port 80. No longer have to worry about your web servers and a particular path. That did the trick for me.

Comment: what all to check in health check

Comment: If you switched you health checks to TCP, your web SERVICE can go down, while your server is still up, and the health checks will pass even though your app is down.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it's just an HTTP GET request looking for a 200 OK http response.